# Excel - Macro - Data copying with values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have a macro where it copies a range from a sheet and pastes it into another sheet.

Sheet name - MAIN
Range - C4 - D26
Date sheet - DATA

Then when you enter new data and use the macro, it copies the data to "DATA SHEET" and pastes it below the original data.

What I'm trying to do is paste the data as values rather than coping the data which brings along the formulas

Below is the macro I'm using......please Help

```
Range("c4:d26").Copy Sheets("DATA").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("C4:c26").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C4").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start with:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub CopyMainToData()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN")

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

Set rngSource = wsMain.Range("C4:D26")

rngSource.Copy

wsData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

rngSource.ClearContents

rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That's greats and it works. One questions I have is how would I be able to select which cells to clear

Comment: You can replace `wsMain.Range("C4:D26")` in the code above with `Selection`.